# Сложный фон вкладок

Tags: svg, html5, css

Стоит задача сделать     [`это`](http://jsfiddle.net/3XxbZ/1/).

Т.е. есть вкладки (по примеру не видно, но при нажатии на вкладку должен меняться контент).

У контейнера вкладок должен быть свой фон - в примере полупрозрачный.

У текущей (активной) вкладки фон должен отсутствовать - должна отображаться картинка из контента, причем отображаться как часть этой самой картинки.

У вкладок скругленные края, фон за краями - полупрозрачный.

Сейчас реализация пока та, что в начале, но мне как-то не нравится то, что для каждой вкладки указывается отдельно картинка и позиция фона.

К тому же - для статичных размеров работает, а если поставить размеры в процентах - уже все плывет. И при изменении статичных размеров придется опять подгонять картинки

С SVG не работал, но читал что вроде как можно сделать аналогично ([пример](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)).

А как это будет работать на всех мобильных девайсах? На SO [писали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889882/svg-support-on-android) что работает не на всех андроидах. На [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/forum/offtopic/31777-gde-ne-rabotaet-svg.html) в ответах приводились ссылки, из которых следует, что вроде как должно работать. А как на самом деле?

К тому же у меня пока толком нет мыслей как использовать SVG чтобы получить искомое решение. Разве что, разделить вкладку на блоки - блок для картинки, блоки сверху и с боков. На картинку накладываем SVG, у блоков ставим полупрозрачный фон, но уверен получится ли то, что нужно.

Есть идеи как это реализовать (с SVG или (лучше) без)? Или подскажите хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться.

Comment: вам прям css надо или js тоже нормально ? я бы начал с идеи вкладок на css с radiobutton

Comment: @eicto, Мне надо, чтобы было "как на рисунке". А вот как это будет сделано - уже не столь важно. Можно еще попробовать сделать то же самое и на канве, но неохота подключать ее только ради этого.

Если будет решение (или его идея) на JS - готов рассмотреть.

Меня бы устроил и мой вариант, но он не масштабируем. Думал о задании позиции и масштаба фона вкладок при помощи JS, но как-то сама идея не понравилась, решил пока отложить - вдруг есть нормальное решение. Хотя если ничего не найду - придется использовать это решение.

А про способ реализации вкладок - не принципиально.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344906/creating-a-hole-in-a-div-element

вам это же надо ? там какая-то мысль про прозрачный png, но у меня не получилось (http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3XxbZ/3/) (может полупрозрачный png нужен на фоне ? (типа alpha не будет складываться))

Comment: [здесь ещё одна идея](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8091563/815386) суть в следующем - сделать боольшой бордер который внутренней частью радиуса перекроет часть diva, не знаю удастся ли вам приемлимые параметры подобрать (бордер только в пикселях бывает)

Comment: на svg можно реализовать хоть всю менюшку,  но оно действительно не на всех андроидах работает. делать можно так - поделить таб бар вертикальными блоками, разделитель типа и картинка с вырезом под таб. но то-же самое можно и на png сделать.

Answer (score 3):

### Решение с помощью тени (`box-shadow`):

Пример передает суть способа - вешаете очень большую тень на активный элемент (вкладку).

```js
'use strict';
$(function() {
  var $tabs = $('.js-tabs');
  var tabActiveClass = 'tabs__item_active';
  
  $tabs.on('click', '.js-tab', function() {
    $tabs.find('.js-tab').not(this).removeClass(tabActiveClass);
    $(this).addClass(tabActiveClass);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Aab7mmc.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tabs__item {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs__item:first-child {
  left: 30px;
}
.tabs__item:last-child {
  right: 30px;
}
.tabs__item_active {
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); // вот и весь фокус, очень большая тень
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tabs js-tabs">
    <div class="tabs__item tabs__item_active js-tab">Вкладка1</div>
    <div class="tabs__item js-tab">Вкладка2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```